# How to send an event to a element in a relative position of the current element

Tags: htmx, hyperscript

I have a list of elements with the class `.node-display`, when one is clicked it becomes an input. I want to capture the down or up arrow keyups to click the very next `.node-display` in the list (relative to the current element).

In the below example, pressing down should click on item 5, and pressing up would click on item 3.

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4 (Currently selected)
- 5
- 6

My best guess is something like this.

```
<input
   _="on keyup[key is 'ArrowDown'] send click to the first .node-display end"
>
```

Does anyone know how I'd actually write this expression?

Comment: I forwarded your question to the discord channel.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to put the behavior on the parent `ul` so you don't have to repeat it on every input.

Something like this:

```html
<ul _="on keydown[key is 'ArrowDown'] from <input/> in me
           set nextSibling to it's parentElement's nextElementSibling
           if nextSibling
             set nextInput to the first <input/> in nextSibling
             call nextInput.focus()
             halt
           end
       on keydown[key is 'ArrowUp'] from <input/> in me
           set previousSibiling to it's parentElement's previousElementSibling
           if previousSibiling
             set previousInput to first <input/> in previousSibiling
             call previousInput.focus()
             halt
           end
       ">
  <li><input/></li>
  <li><input/></li>
  <li><input/></li>
  <li><input/></li>
</ul>
```

Some notes on this code:

- I am using the `from` from in the event handler, which puts the element that the event came from into the `it` symbol
- I am using the `keydown` event so we can cancel the event with the `halt` command, to avoid the down and up keys changing the caret position
- I am using the `halt` command to stop the event from propogating
- I used `focus` rather than click as a proof of concept